# Conditional Probabilities Combination

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I'm trying to do the following homework problem and am stuck trying to figure out how to manipulate the conditional probabilities given to me.

P(A) = .75

P(B|A) = .9

$P(B|A^ c )$ = .8

$P(C|A\cap B)$ = .8

$P(C|A \cap B^ c )$ = .6

$P(C|A^c \cap B)$ = .7

$P(C|A^ c \cap B^ c )$ = .3

Given the following information I'm trying to get the following:

1.) P(A intersection B intersection C)

2.) P(B intersection C)

3.) P(C)

4.) P(A|B intersection C)

I was able to figure out the first one to be P(A) * P(B|A) * P(C|A intersection B) = (.75)(.09)(.08) = .054

I'm not sure how to get the rest however and am stuck.

Note: I will go back and edit this once I figure out how to format the symbols correctly.

EDIT:

I found the answers but don't really know how to get to them. The answers are as follows:

P(C) = .74

P(B n C) = .68

P(A|B n C) = .7941

Comment: Can you use cleaner notation. What's "c complement". Do you just mean $A^c$. Also this is ambiguous "A intersection B c complement". Do you mean $A \cap B^c$ or $(A\cap B)^c$.

Comment: Yes to first question and yes to how you formatted in the first of the 2 choices for the second question. I'm trying to figure out how to format this question to have it written out the way you typed it

Comment: @KaiSikorski how do you format the text to look that way?

Comment: I just type LaTeX between "$" signs.

Comment: What is the value of $P(C|A^c\cap B^c)$? Are all of the other values greater than .5?

Comment: it's .3 @user84413

Comment: Thanks - Also, is P(B|A)=.9 or .09, and is $P(C|A\cap B)=.8$ or .08?

Comment: Drawing a Venn Diagram/Karnaugh map is useful in this sort of problem.

Comment: @user84413: it's .8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here goes...

$P(A^c) = 1 - P(A) = 1 - \frac34 = \frac14$

$P(A \cap B) = P(B|A)P(A) = \frac 9{10} \times  \frac34 = \frac{27}{40}$

$P(A^c \cap B) = P(B|A^c)P(A^c) = \frac 8{10} \times \frac 14 = \frac 8{40}$

$P(B) = P(A \cap B) + P(A^c \cap B) = \frac{27}{40} + \frac8{40} = \frac{35}{40}$

$P(B^c) = 1 - P(B) = 1 - \frac{35}{40} = \frac5{40}$

$P(A \cap B^c) = p(A) - p(A \cap B) = \frac34 - \frac{27}{40} = \frac3{40} $

$P(A^c \cap B^c) = P(B^c) - P(A \cap B^c) = \frac5{40} - \frac3{40} = \frac2{40}$

$P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(C|A \cap B)p(A \cap B) = \frac8{10} \times \frac{27}{40} = \frac{27}{50} $

$P(A^c \cap B \cap C) = P(C|A^c \cap B)p(A^c \cap B) = \frac7{10} \times \frac8{40} = \frac7{50}$

$P(A \cap B^c \cap C) = P(C|A \cap B^c)p(A \cap B^c) = \frac6{10} \times \frac3{40} = \frac{18}{400}$

$P(A^c \cap B^c \cap C) = P(C|A^c \cap B^c)p(A^c \cap B^c) = \frac3{10} \times \frac2{40} = \frac6{400}$

$P(C) = P(A \cap B \cap C)+ P(A^c \cap B \cap C)+P(A \cap B^c \cap C)+P(A^c \cap B^c \cap C) = \frac{34}{50} + \frac{24}{400} = \frac{148}{200} $

$P(B \cap C) = P(A \cap B \cap C) + P(A^c \cap B \cap C) = \frac{27}{50} + \frac7{50} = \frac{34}{50}$

$P(A|B \cap C) = P(A \cap B \cap C)/P(B \cap C) = (\frac{27}{50})/(\frac{34}{50}) = \frac{27}{34}$

Required answers are given respectively by 8th, 13th, 12th and 14th of these equations. Note there is some reliance 0n $P(X) = P(X \cap Y) + P(X \cap Y^c)$ which is used to calculate $P(B)$, $P(A \cap B^c)$, $P(A^c \cap B^c)$, $P(C)$ (using an extended form) and $P(B \cap C)$.

Comment: This is extremely useful! Not the answers but showing how each conditional works since I've been struggling heavily trying to understand how each one works. Huge thanks for this!!!